# Frequency Array with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem on codeforces it's about the frequency array this is the link of the problem https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/219774/problem/V

and this is my code:

```
N , M = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(1,M+1):
    print(A.count(i))
```

But this code is so slow, I've got time limit exceeded on test 2.

Comment: try sorting A and then find the frequency in a single go, with this it will have O(nlogn) right now you have O(N*M)

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work

Comment: Instead of reading all numbers of the second line into an array, you could aswell create an array of counts. This way, you achieve O(N+M).

Comment: Use hash map, I just submitted and it got accepted with 233ms, check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
N , M = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

pool = {}

for i in A:
  if i in pool:
    pool[i] += 1
  else:
    pool[i] = 1


for i in range(1,M+1):
    print(pool.get(i, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

`.count()` takes O(N) time and you are doing it for every element of the input list leading to a time complexity of O(N^2) and that's why you're getting TLE.

You need to store the frequency of each item in a `dictionary` by iterating only once and then print them at last. **Time Complexity: O(N + M)**

Try this.

```
from collections import Counter
N , M = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
c = Counter(A)

for i in range(1,M+1):
    print(c[i])
```

Comment: Your solution has time complexity O(N+M), *not* O(N).

Answer (score 1):

No need for any import:

```py
N , M = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
cnt = M * [0]
for str_i in input().split():
    cnt[int(str_i)-1] += 1
for c in cnt:
    print(c)
```